Reduce number of connected nodes to my private rpc nodes
I wonder if there is a way to reduce the number of connected peers to my private RPC node. When I run the command solana gossip I see that there are around 5.5k other nodes. Does that mean that my node exchanges messages with all of these nodes? And how can I check which nodes my RPC node is connected to directly?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Your node is not directly connected to every other node, but all nodes are aware of how to contact each other. For example, for turbine, your node needs to know where to distribute shreds to other nodes so that they can keep up with the network. And upstream nodes need to know how to send shreds to your node. Over turbine, the target nodes get shuffled for every single shred of a block, and a block can contain thousands of shreds.
Over time, if stake weight changes, your node may need to send and receive to whole different sets of nodes, so it'll need contact information for all them. The contact information (among other info) is distributed to other nodes over the gossip protocol, which has its own rules about how it chooses nodes to contact.
All that to say, if your node participates in gossip, you can't really limit the number of other nodes you're connected to. You could connect to another service like Jito's shredstream to receive shreds outside of the normal protocol operation, but within the base Solana protocol, you can't limit connections to other nodes.
